# Is there a downloadable corpus (dictionary/ lexicon) for informal, playful words such as 'gonna', 'LOL', 'wanna' in English?

Tags: nlp, corpus, linguistics, lexicon

Please suggest me a downloadable English corpus that contains informal, playful words such as 'gonna', 'LOL' and 'wanna'

Comment: Twitter is full of informal language. You can stream as much as you want in real time, but unfortunately you are not allowed to distributed the data you collect.

Comment: No, what I meant is the availability of a dictionary (corpus/ lexicon) for informal, playful words that can be used for researches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 'NetLingo'. They have a rich content :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know such lexicon but you can try to do this, alternatively:

- Get the vocabulary *V1* of Twitter or other web and chat corpus.
- Get the vocabulary *V2* of literary corpus.

The lexicon you want might be *V1 \ V2* i.e. all the words of *V1* which are not in *V2*.

Using Python, [NLTK provides corpora](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch02.html) (see `nltk.corpus.webtext`). Moreover, as @mbatchkarov said in the comments: Twitter is full of informal language.